# how to link yaml file in concourse?

Tags: docker, devops, concourse

In my task I have

`file: tasks/build-task-config.yml`

`unknown artifact source: 'tasks' in task config file path 'tasks/build-task-config.yml'`

I'm running concourse via docker-compose

- ci/

  - pipeline.yml
  - tasks/

    - build-task-config.yml

Above is my directory structure.

This is how I run fly

`fly -t tutorial set-pipeline -c ./ci/main-pipeline.yml -p test-frontend`

1. How I can resolve this issue?
2. How do paths works in Concourse ?

Edit:
I've tried with path `ci/tasks/build-task-config.yml` but it's also not working

Comment: Paths are relative. Could you please post the entire pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

You need an input to the task called `tasks`. This may come from a `get:` step, or as the output of a previous task. Most likely you have a `get` with your repo that has this code (let's pretend it's called `source`). If that's the case, then your task should look like this

```
- task: build-task-config # Or whatever name you want
  file: source/ci/tasks/build-task-config.yml
  ...
```

Everything has to be relative to an input in a task, if it's not part of the base image.

Comment: Does concourse always needs to pull some files from git repository?
I've resolved my issues by simply using yaml anchors, but I'm struggling with ansible right now - I really don't want to mess up my repository when I'm testing different tasks etc.

Comment: No, not always, but it must have access to the file in the filesystem of the container. Usually this comes from the task inputs, though it's possible you've baked them into the image.